# Error en Procedimiento SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

tengo este procedimiento en el cual me salta un error de sintaxis en la linea 53 la cual corresponde a las ultimas lineas del procedimiento, la cuestión es que el sistema me identifica como erróneo dos dobles comillas simples ('') pero no logro distinguir ese error en esas lineas del procedimiento.

***ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 53***

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CONFIGURACION;

DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE CONFIGURACION(IN ipv4 VARCHAR(15), IN mascara VARCHAR(15),
                                      IN puerta VARCHAR(15), OUT resultado TEXT)

BEGIN
     DECLARE 1byteIP VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT '';
     DECLARE 1byteGW VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT '';
     DECLARE 2byteIP VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT '';
     DECLARE 2byteGW VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT '';
     DECLARE 3byteIP VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT '';
     DECLARE 3byteGW VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT '';
     
     SET resultado = 'La configuracion IPv4: \n\n';


     IF (mascara LIKE '255.255.255.0') OR (mascara LIKE '255.255.0.0') OR (mascara LIKE '255.0.0.0') THEN
          SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado, '\ Con Direccion IPV4 --> ', ipv4);
          SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado, '\ Con mascara --> ', mascara);
          SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado, '\ Con gateway IPV4 --> ', puerta);
          IF mascara LIKE '255.0.0.0' THEN
               SET 1byteIP =SUBSTRING(ipv4,1,locate('.', ipv4)-1);
               SET 1byteGW =SUBSTRING(puerta,1,locate('.', puerta)-1);
               IF 1byteIP LIKE 1byteGW THEN
                    SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado, '\n\n Es Correcta');
               ELSE
                    SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado, '\n\n Es INCORRECTA');
               END IF;
          END IF;
          IF mascara LIKE '255.255.0.0' THEN
               SET 2byteIP = SUBSTRING(ipv4,1,LOCATE('.', ipv4, LOCATE('.', ipv4)+1)-1);
               SET 2byteGW = SUBSTRING(puerta,1,LOCATE('.', puerta,LOCATE('.', puerta)+1)-1);
               IF 2byteIP LIKE 2byteGW THEN
                    SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado, '\n\n Es CORRECTA');
               ELSE
                    SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado, '\n\n Es INCORRECTA');
               END IF;
          END IF;
          IF mascara LIKE '255.255.255.0' THEN
               SET 3byteIP = SUBSTRING(ipv4,1,LOCATE('.', ipv4, LOCATE('.', ipv4)+1)-1);
               SET 3byteGW = SUBSTRING(puerta,1,LOCATE('.', puerta,LOCATE('.', puerta)+1)-1);
               IF 3byteIP LIKE 3byteGW THEN
                    SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado, ' \n\n Es CORRECTA');
               ELSE
                    SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado, ' \n\n Es INCORRECTA');
               END IF;
          END IF;

     SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado,'Con direccion IPv4   -->', ipv4, '\n');
     SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado,'Con mascara de red   -->', mascara, '\n');        
     SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado,'Con puerta de enlace  -->', puerta, '\n'); 
     SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado); 


END |

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: y cual es la linea 53?

Comment: se supone que la linea del END y el DELIMITER

Comment: Te falta un END IF;

Comment: Bien visto @juanrpozo ..

Comment: Ostras, tienes razón, gracias. Madre mia...

Answer (score 2):

Te comento; que te hace un `END IF;` el que corresponde a `IF (mascara LIKE '255.255.255.0') OR (mascara LIKE '255.255.0.0') OR (mascara LIKE '255.0.0.0') THEN` ¿Donde va? depende de la lógica que estes manejando.

Así mismo, el ultimo `SET resultado = CONCAT(resultado);` no es necesario además que puede generarte error pues deben ser 2 parámetros que reciba.